# React Express Localhost Proxy 404

Tags: reactjs, express, proxy, postman, create-react-app

I am developing a MERN app and have been using create-react-app's proxy feature to send requests to my Express server. I added the proxy flag in my client package.json file as such

```
"name": "mern",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        ALL DEPENDENCIES REMOVED FOR BREVITY
   },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "dev": "(cd backend && nodemon server) & npm run start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
```

I am also using relative paths in my React app. Things were working beautifully, but one day, I began receiving 404 errors from the React app, and errors in the terminal saying that there is a bad request. I haven't changed any proxy settings. The proxy server works with Postman and I can fetch data from my API, but with React/Axios, it continuously returns 404 Bad Request, ERR EMPTY RESPONSE, or ERRCONREFUSED errors.

**EDIT: Axios Instance Creation and API Routes**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Redirect, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import useForm from '../Helpers/CustomHooks'
import Logo from '../imgs/logo-zephyr.png'
import auth from '../Helpers/AuthService'
import validate from '../Helpers/ValidationRules'

if (auth.loggedIn()) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common['authorization'] = auth.getToken()
}

if (!auth.isValid(auth.getToken())) {
    auth.setToken(null)
}
const Login = props => {
    const { user, setUser } = props

    const [tel, setTel] = useState(null)
    const [valid, setValid] = useState(false)
    const [code, setCode] = useState('')
    const [loginForm, setLoginForm] = useState(null)
    const [isComplete, setIsComplete] = useState(false)
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)
    const [authorized, setAuthorized] = useState(null)
    const [send, setSend] = useState(false)
    const [validverify, setValidverify] = useState(false)

    const isEmpty = obj => {
        if (obj) {
            return Object.keys(obj).length === 0
        } else {
            return null
        }
    }
    const form = document.getElementById('login')
    const verify = (e, code) => {
        setError(null)
        e.preventDefault()
        axios.defaults.headers.common['authorization'] = auth.getToken()
        axios
            .post('/api/verifycheck', {
                tel: tel,
                code: code,
                token: auth.getToken(),
            })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                if (typeof res.data === 'string' || res.data.err) {
                    setError(res.data.err)
                }
                auth.setToken(res.data.token)
                const profile = auth.getProfile()
                setUser(profile.user)
                setAuthorized(profile.authorized)
                setValid(true)
                setTel(null)
                setSend(false)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
                setError(err.response.data)
            })
    }
    const diffLog = () => {
        console.log(form)

        if (form) {
            form.reset()
        }
        auth.setToken(null)
        setTel(null)
    }
    const handleVerify = e => {
        e.persist()
        setCode(e.target.value)
        if (e.target.value.length === 6) {
            setValidverify(true)
        }
    }
    const verifyPrompt = tel => {
        setError(null)
        axios
            .get('/api/verify', {
                params: {
                    tel: tel,
                },
            })
            .then(res => {
                //too many requests, throw error saying wait specified period of time
                setValid(res.data.valid)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
                err.response && setError(err.response.data)
                err.response && console.log(err.response.data)
            })
    }
    const initialValues = {
        password1: '',
        username: '',
    }

    const login = async () => {
        try {
            const data = await auth.login(inputs.username, inputs.password1)
            auth.setToken(data.token)
            if (auth.loggedIn()) {
                try {
                    const profile = auth.getProfile()
                    setUser(profile.user)
                    setAuthorized(profile.authorized)
                    setTel(profile.user.phoneNumber)
                    setSend(true)
                } catch (err) {
                    auth.logout()
                }
            } else {
                console.log('not logged in')
            }
        } catch (err) {
            err.response && console.log(err.response.data.err)
            setError(err.response.data.err)
        }
    }
    const {
        validationErrors,
        inputs,
        handleInputChange,
        handleSubmit,
        handleBlur,
        handleClick,
    } = useForm(login, initialValues, validate)

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoginForm(form)
    }, [form])
    useEffect(() => {
        if (tel && send) {
            verifyPrompt(tel)
        }
    }, [tel, send])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (authorized) setValid(authorized)
    }, [authorized])
    useEffect(() => {
        if (auth.loggedIn()) {
            try {
                const profile = auth.getProfile()
                setAuthorized(profile.authorized)
                setUser(profile.user)
                setTel(profile.user.phoneNumber)
            } catch (err) {
                auth.logout()
            }
        }
    }, [setUser])
    useEffect(() => {
        let values = Object.values(inputs)
        console.log(values)
        let areAnyValsEmpty = values.some(element => element.length === 0)
        console.log(
            isEmpty(validationErrors),
            isComplete,
            areAnyValsEmpty,
            error
        )
        if (isEmpty(validationErrors) && !areAnyValsEmpty) {
            setIsComplete(true)
        }
    }, [error, inputs, validationErrors])
    if (auth.loggedIn() && user && valid) {
        return <Redirect to={`/${user._id}/profile`} />
    }

    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-3 img-pane">
                    <img className="img-fluid" src={Logo} alt="logo.png" />
                </div>
                <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 registration">
                    <h3>Login</h3>
                    {!tel && (
                        <form id="login" onSubmit={() => login()}>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <input
                                    className={`form-control zephyr-input ${validationErrors &&
                                        validationErrors.username &&
                                        'input-danger'}`}
                                    required
                                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                                    value={inputs.username}
                                    type="text"
                                    name="username"
                                    id="username"
                                    placeholder="Enter username or email"
                                />
                                {validationErrors && (
                                    <p className="text-danger">
                                        {validationErrors.username}
                                    </p>
                                )}
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <input
                                    className={`form-control zephyr-input ${validationErrors &&
                                        validationErrors.password1 &&
                                        'input-danger'}`}
                                    required
                                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                                    value={inputs.password1}
                                    type="password"
                                    name="password1"
                                    id="password1"
                                    placeholder="Enter password"
                                />
                                {validationErrors && (
                                    <p className="text-danger">
                                        {validationErrors.password1}
                                    </p>
                                )}
                            </div>
                            <button
                                disabled={error || !isComplete}
                                onClick={handleSubmit}
                                className="btn btn-success btn-block mb-3 form-button"
                                type="button"
                            >
                                Login
                            </button>
                            <SignUpLink />
                        </form>
                    )}
                    {tel && !authorized && !valid && (
                        <form onSubmit={e => verify(e, code)}>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <input
                                    className="form-control zephyr-input"
                                    onChange={handleVerify}
                                    value={code || ''}
                                    type="code"
                                    name="code"
                                    id="code"
                                    placeholder="Enter 6-digit verification code"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <button
                                disabled={!validverify}
                                className="btn btn-success btn-block form-button"
                                type="submit"
                            >
                                Verify
                            </button>
                            <button
                                onClick={() => verifyPrompt(tel)}
                                className="btn btn-warning btn-block form-button"
                                type="button"
                            >
                                Resend Code
                            </button>
                            <Link onClick={() => diffLog()} to="/login">
                                Login with a Different Account
                            </Link>
                        </form>
                    )}
                    {error && <div className="alert alert-danger">{error}</div>}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}


export default Login
```

Comment: the proxy only works of `/api/` is located in the path. would u share the code. also the instance creation of axios.

Comment: @SamHamada added an example of how I'm making API calls, and how Axios is being created.